# link to the project's root URL in mailService

Tags: grails

in Grails project  i need to put the project's root link in the email body , using mailService in [Mail plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/mail) , is this the proper way or there are some better ways ,  here is my code :

```
def webUtils = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
def request = webUtils.getCurrentRequest()
def link ="http://" + request.serverName+'/'+grails.util.Metadata.current.'app.name'
```

Comment: U can put the root link in `Config.groovy` instead of writing this verbose code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating the link using the `createLink` or `link` tags.

```
<g:link uri='/' absolute='true'>My Link</g:link>
<!-- OR -->
<a href="${g.createLink(uri: '/', absolute: true)}">MyLink</a>
```

Using *absolute* ensures the link is prefixed with **grails.serverURL** from your configuration.